# Node Tree break down as Array

Tags: php

is that possible to generate the array base one this node tree? That is the code that I have done. But I have no idea how to create 1,3,2 and 1,4 as an array. And I don't know how to make it more efficient.
is that possible to generate the array base one this node tree? That is the code that I have done. But I have no idea how to create 1,3,2 and 1,4 as an array. And I don't know how to make it more efficient.

That is the array:

```
 array (
  'pole number 1' => 
  array (
    0 => 'pole number 1',
    1 => 'TRUE',
    'children' => 
    array (
      'pole number 3' => 
      array (
        0 => 'pole number 3',
        1 => 'FALSE',
        2 => 'pole number 1',
        'children' => 
        array (
          'pole number 2' => 
          array (
            0 => 'pole number 2',
            1 => 'FALSE',
            2 => 'pole number 3',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      'pole number 4' => 
      array (
        0 => 'pole number 4',
        1 => 'FALSE',
        2 => 'pole number 1',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'pole number 5' => 
  array (
    0 => 'pole number 5',
    1 => 'TRUE',
    'children' => 
    array (
      'pole number 6' => 
      array (
        0 => 'pole number 6',
        1 => 'FALSE',
        2 => 'pole number 5',
        'children' => 
        array (
          'pole number 7' => 
          array (
            0 => 'pole number 7',
            1 => 'FALSE',
            2 => 'pole number 6',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      'pole number 8' => 
      array (
        0 => 'pole number 8',
        1 => 'FALSE',
        2 => 'pole number 5',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

```
1
--3
---2
--4
```

Expected Output

```
[
 [1,3,2],
 [1,4]
]
```

```
foreach ($tree as $key => $value) {
    $result = traverseTree($value);
}

function traverseTree($tree = array())
{
    if ($tree[1] && !empty($tree['children'])) {
        // if no parent id than that is root
        $result[$tree[0]] = $tree[0];
        traverseTree($tree['children']);
    } else {
        foreach ($tree as $key => $node) {
            var_dump($node[1]);
            if ($node[1]) {
                $result[$node[2]][] = $node[0];
            }
        }
    }

    var_dump($result);
}
```

Comment: _is that possible_ yes.

Comment: How could i do ?

Comment: Are you familiar with recursion?

Comment: Yes, I use the recursion to generate the tree, but i have no idea to create the array :(

Comment: So you can start with recursion and show us what you have tried.

Comment: Just updated the code to the post what I have done.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Actually you would need to add current node to the list of arrays returned from child nodes. I will try and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursion strategy seems to be ok but you need to push another recursion call to stack by passing the `children` array if it is set. Next is to loop over each individual result subarray returned from the recursion call and current key name to it as shown below.

```
<?php

function collectNodes($tree){
    $result = [];
    foreach($tree as $name => $details){
        if(isset($details['children'])){
            $sub_result = collectNodes($details['children']);
            foreach($sub_result as $sr){
                $sr = array_merge([$name],$sr);
                $result[] = $sr;
            }
        }else{
            $result[] = [$name];
        }
    }    
    return $result;
}

print_r(collectNodes($tree));
```

**Demo:** http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bb826c6ce98976ce2b4c694946d79e765f4b6330